# How to create a "gap" in a barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart

How do I achieve a "gap" in a barplot, like this:

[image: barplot with gap]

I tried to create an empty column in my contingency table, but couldn't.

---

Sample data:

```
groups = c("A", "B")
choices = c("orange", "apple", "beer")
dat <- data.frame(
    group = rep(groups, c(93, 94)),
    choice = factor(c(
            rep(choices, c(51, 30, 12)),
            rep(choices, c(47, 29, 18))
        ),
        levels = choices
    )
)
barplot(table(dat), beside = TRUE)
```

[image: original barplot]

Comment: At first glance it looks like you should be able to use the `space` argument like `barplot(table(dat), beside = TRUE, space = c(1.5, 1.5, 3))` but it doesn't seem to work with `beside = TRUE`.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, @Marius. What I might need to do is add a third variable that groups "orange" and "apple" together. I'll try ...

Comment: I was able to figure it out, you need to think in terms of the 6 bars that are plotted, running left to right, and manually specify spaces for them. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
barplot(table(dat), beside = TRUE,
        space = c(0, 0, 1.5, 0, 3, 0))
```

The logic for the `space` values is fiddly:

- You don't need space before the first bar- first value is 0
- You don't need space between the first and second bars (the two "orange" bars)
- You need the standard amount of space before the first bar of "apple"
- You need extra space before the first "beer" bar

Result:

[image]